# flag a file as a config file in a Debian package

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

The usual search terms get a little confused when I try to Google this.

I'm trying to figure out how one flags a file as a configuration file while building a Debian package (debuild). According to the [Debian policies](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html) there should be a way to flag a file as a `conf` file so that the user is prompted. If the file is different than the version being installed. I know such a feature exists (e.g. when you try to update grub, such a check is preformed on /etc/default/grub), but can't seem to find any docs/references on how one enables this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `conffiles` file in the DEBIAN directory and declare what files are config files in it. These files will be automatically considered configuration files, and changes to it will prompt a "new config file, would you want to overwrite...".

> dh_installdeb(1) automatically flags any files under the /etc directory as conffiles, so if your program only has conffiles there you do not need to specify them in this file. For most package types, the only place conffiles should ever be is under /etc, and so this file doesn't need to exist.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles